# How to edit Magento current logged user details via php code

Tags: php, magento

`$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    $customer_id = $session->getId(); 
    $customer_data = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
    print_r($customer_data);`

Through this code ican get user details
I need to know How to edit the user details like address,password ..etc in the same Way using Php codes
Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php magic get and set methods

Suppose to set password you can use `$customer_data->setPassword('1234567');`

```
$customer_data->save();
```

For customer address

```
$_custom_address = array (
'firstname' => 'firstname',
'lastname' => 'lastname',
'street' => array (
    '0' => 'Sample address part1',
    '1' => 'Sample address part2',
),
'city' => 'city',
'region_id' => '',
'region' => '',
'postcode' => '31000',
'country_id' => 'US', 
'telephone' => '0038531555444',
);

$customAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')

$customAddress->setData($_custom_address)
        ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
        ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
        ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
        ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');

try {
    $customAddress->save();
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    //Zend_Debug::dump($ex->getMessage());
}
```

For more info http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programming-magento/programatically-create-customer-and-order-in-magento-with-full-blown-one-page-checkout-process-under-the-hood/

Comment: This is very helpful .. Thank you very much Mufaddal.  
Can you please provide the Code to get the current logined user's password
and code for setting a new Password via code for that user.
Please Mention all the models declared,
Thank you Very much

Answer (score 4):

for Password you can set using $customer_id

```
$password = 'Any Things'
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
$customer->setPassword($password);
$customer->save();
```

For Edit address you have to load address model

For Example if you want to edit billing Address :

```
 $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
 $address = $customer->getDefaultBilling();

 $address->setFirstname("Test");
 $address->save();
```

OR : 
using address id get from customer object :

```
   $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customerAddressId);
   $address->setFirstname("Test"); 
   $address->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use methods of Mage_Customer_Model_Customer class:

```
$customerSession = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
$customerModel = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerSession->getId());
$customerModel->changePassword('new_password');
```